# Checking in a new bag during a layover

Tags: layovers, shopping, south-korea, seoul

I will have a 10 hour layover in Seoul (ICN) and I want to go out and do some shopping. Is it possible to check in a bag during my layover?  I will be traveling on Korean Air.

I will only have 1 checked bag, and international flights allow 2 bags free.

Answer (score 4):

The same questions showed up in [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k6988384-Checking_Bag_Only_During_Layover-Air_Travel.html), and on [FlyerTalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/us-airways-dividend-miles-pre-consolidation/1476302-checking-bag-during-stopover.html) even though not with the same airport or airline. In TripAdvisor one traveler mentions he checked a new bag during a stop in Amsterdam flying by KLM and he had no problem. On FlyerTalk another traveler says he checked a new luggage during a layover in Frankfurt (doesn't mention which airline he was traveling) and had no issues too.

I couldn't find an authoritative answer from Korean Air to this question, but see no point to forbid a bag check-in during a layover and it seems to be allowed in other airlines.

Of course you should mind that checking a bag may be time-consuming so you should arrive in the terminal earlier than if you had no other luggages, but 10 hours should be enough time for the shopping and bag checking procedures.

Comment: You should also consider the fee you might have to pay for the extra item of luggage.

Comment: OP mentions that "international flights allow 2 bags free.". It is not true for every carrier, but should be true for his ticket in Korean Airlines, I suppose.