# Checking bags internationally

Tags: air-travel, luggage

Can you check bags from an international flight through an airport if that airport is a stopover for a domestic flight. Even if it’s the same airline?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question. It's not quite clear what it is about.

Comment: Please also clarify exactly which airports you're flying through/to.

Comment: I have experienced both where I had to recheck the bags and I was allowed to check through. You need to specify the airport and airline.

Comment: If you don't want to mention airline and airport, at least give the country you're flying to; while this might not be enough to be sure it's possible, it might be enough to tell you that checking through is not possible.

Comment: Relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42389/checking-in-a-new-bag-during-a-layover

Answer (score 3):

At least the following cases exist:

- flight from outside the US to a first city in the US, and then on to another city (in th US or not), on a single ticket:

  - you check your bags to your final destination
  - but you have to go through passport control, reclaim your bags, go through customs, and drop your bags again for your next flight (but there’s usually a counter for this right after customs, no need to go to check-in desks, the bags are already tagged to the final destination)
- flight from outside the EU to a first city in the EU, then another city in the EU where the airport has customs facilities, with both flights on the same ticket:

  - you check your bags through to your final destination
  - you won’t see your bags until your final destination.
- your flights are on separate tickets on separate airlines with no partnership agreement:

  - you will have to check and reclaim your bags for each of your flights

There are plenty of other cases, but the details will vary depending on the specifics. For instance, some airlines will accept checking your luggage through for flights on separate tickets, some will not (especially low cost carriers). You will need to provide more details regarding the airline and the airports involved (and whether the flights are on the same ticket or not) if you want to know more.

Comment: The EU rule applies to all flights, not only those originating in the US

Comment: @Sabine it was meant as an example, but indeed I can generalise it.